# How to, call a c# function in code behind of parent page from silverlight plugin on that page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

1. aspx page ASPX
2. silverlight plugin SL on ASPX page

I wrote a method in C# on an ASPX page as a C# script.

How do I call the C# method on a button click in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

When you're interacting with your Silverlight app on the client it technically doesn't matter where the ASPX page and the Silverlight app are. I believe you will need to set up the aspx code behind to be used as a `WebMethod` and use silverlight to interact with it just like you would if you were using AJAX.

I imagine a Google search would turn up tutorials on how to consume a web service, which shouldn't be any different then doing it in your code behind of your aspx page.

Comment: i got this by search "How to call Server Side function from Client Side Code using PageMethods in ASP.NET AJAX""http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109" is it the same thing, what would be a good place to start for webmethod